# jedi-vim: modules from non-standard paths

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, jedi-vim

I have different local python installations that were built with [hashdist](https://github.com/hashdist/hashdist). 
On the other hand, vim is installed system-wide (ArchLinux) referencing the system's python3.

I would like to use jedi's autocompletion for packages of one isolated python build. The modules lie in `some/path/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is not known to the system python (hence, vim). Also, vim was compiled for python3; that "other version"  is python2.7.

Is there any way to do this? If I could just pick one specific package that would be fine, too. $PYTHONPATH doesn't work (at least) because of the conflicting python versions.

Comment: Possibly try http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jedi intentionally only works for the same Python version, because compiled packages might cause seg faults (when loading them). Therefore this is not something that is even intended by Jedi.

However you can modify the `sys.path` in jedi-vim itself, if you want to play with it `:python3 sys.path.append()`. But that's really not recommended.

Comment: Same version, e.g. 2.7, or same build/installation?
Supposing I used vim with "system python2.7", would it work then for the setup described above?

Comment: Well I have no idea how VIM itself uses Python. I have never looked into it. Basically completion works in the packages that are included in the `sys.path`, since that is the starting point. It's not really possible to get another starting point.